# Passing on a C library callback to a NodeJS EventEmitter using node-addon-api

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, hid, node-addon-api

I am currently working on writing a node module that binds Alex Diner's [cross-platform gamepad code](https://github.com/ThemsAllTook/libstem_gamepad) using the [Node-Addon-API](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api).

For the most part, this was a fairly easy task.
Only problematic are the callback functions of the Gamepad library.

My idea is to expose these callbacks via `.on(...)` by making the module an EventEmitter. It was already done in a similar way with the [Nan module](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) in [this node module](https://github.com/creationix/node-gamepad).

The problem is, whenever an event is fired from my native module, I get the following error:

```
internal/timers.js:531
          timer._onTimeout();
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined
    at emit (events.js:163:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

The important parts of my `binding.cc`:

```
#include <napi.h>
#include "gamepad/Gamepad.h" // The Gamepad library written by Alex Diner

// The JS .emit(event, ...args) function from the EventEmitter
Napi::FunctionReference emitFn;

void GamepadSetEmitFn(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();

    if (info.Length() < 1) {
        Napi::TypeError::New(env, "Parameter 'emitFn' needs to be defined.")
            .ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return;
    }

    if (!info[0].IsFunction()) {
        Napi::TypeError::New(env, "Parameter 'emitFn' needs to be a function.")
            .ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return;
    }
    // Sets the emitFn to the specified function
    emitFn = Napi::Persistent(info[0].As<Napi::Function>());
}

// The following handle functions are the callbacks for the actual Gamepad module

void HandleDeviceAttach(struct Gamepad_device* device, void* context) {
    if (emitFn == nullptr) return;

    Napi::Env env = emitFn.Env();
    Napi::String eventName = Napi::String::New(env, "attach");
    Napi::Number nDeviceID = Napi::Number::New(env, device->deviceID);
    emitFn.Call({ eventName, nDeviceID });
}

void HandleDeviceRemove(struct Gamepad_device* device, void* context) {
    if (emitFn == nullptr) return;

    Napi::Env env = emitFn.Env();
    Napi::String eventName = Napi::String::New(env, "remove");
    Napi::Number nDeviceID = Napi::Number::New(env, device->deviceID);
    emitFn.Call({ eventName, nDeviceID });
}

void HandleButtonDown(struct Gamepad_device* device, unsigned int buttonID, double timestamp, void* context) {
    if (emitFn == nullptr) return;

    Napi::Env env = emitFn.Env();
    Napi::String eventName = Napi::String::New(env, "down");
    Napi::Number nDeviceID = Napi::Number::New(env, device->deviceID);
    Napi::Number nButtonID = Napi::Number::New(env, buttonID);
    Napi::Number nTimestamp = Napi::Number::New(env, timestamp);
    emitFn.Call({ eventName, nDeviceID, nButtonID, nTimestamp });
}

void HandleButtonUp(struct Gamepad_device* device, unsigned int buttonID, double timestamp, void* context) {
    if (emitFn == nullptr) return;

    Napi::Env env = emitFn.Env();
    Napi::String eventName = Napi::String::New(env, "up");
    Napi::Number nDeviceID = Napi::Number::New(env, device->deviceID);
    Napi::Number nButtonID = Napi::Number::New(env, buttonID);
    Napi::Number nTimestamp = Napi::Number::New(env, timestamp);
    emitFn.Call({ eventName, nDeviceID, nButtonID, nTimestamp });
}

void HandleAxisMovement(struct Gamepad_device* device, unsigned int axisID, float value, float lastValue, double timestamp, void* context) {
    if (emitFn == nullptr) return;

    Napi::Env env = emitFn.Env();
    Napi::String eventName = Napi::String::New(env, "move");
    Napi::Number nDeviceID = Napi::Number::New(env, device->deviceID);
    Napi::Number nAxisID = Napi::Number::New(env, axisID);
    Napi::Number nValue = Napi::Number::New(env, value);
    Napi::Number nLastValue = Napi::Number::New(env, lastValue);
    Napi::Number nTimestamp = Napi::Number::New(env, timestamp);
    emitFn.Call({ eventName, nDeviceID, nAxisID, nValue, nLastValue, nTimestamp });
}

Napi::Object InitAll(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {

    // Applies the specified callback functions above to the respective Gamepad function.
    Gamepad_deviceAttachFunc(HandleDeviceAttach, NULL);
    Gamepad_deviceRemoveFunc(HandleDeviceRemove, NULL);
    Gamepad_buttonDownFunc(HandleButtonDown, NULL);
    Gamepad_buttonUpFunc(HandleButtonUp, NULL);
    Gamepad_axisMoveFunc(HandleAxisMovement, NULL);

    // All functionality exposed to JS
    // (including the function implementations omitted from this stackoverflow excerpt)
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "init"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadInit));
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "shutdown"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadShutdown));
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "detectDevices"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadDetectDevices));
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "processEvents"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadProcessEvents));
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "numDevices"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadNumDevices));
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "deviceAtIndex"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadDeviceAtIndex));
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "setEmitFn"), Napi::Function::New(env, GamepadSetEmitFn));

    return exports;
}
```

And the `index.js` that connects the C++ module with the EventEmitter:

```
const gamepad = require('../build/Release/gamepad.node')
const { EventEmitter } = require('events')

// Makes the native module extend 'EventEmitter'
gamepad.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype

// Exposes the emit function to the native module
gamepad.setEmitFn(gamepad.emit)

module.exports = gamepad
```

If more information is needed, dont hesitate to ask!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to solve this by myself. I am not sure why this is a problem, but the error happens due to the fact that I am calling the .emit(event, ...args) method from the EventEmitter class directly from C++.

I simply added a wrapper function to my module from JavaScript, and now it works like a charm:

```
const gamepad = require('../build/Release/gamepad.node')
const { EventEmitter } = require('events')

// Makes the native module extend 'EventEmitter'
gamepad.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype

// Wraps the emit function for the call from the native module
gamepad.applyEmit = (...args) => { 
    const event = args.shift()
    gamepad.emit(event, ...args)
}

// Exposes the applyEmit function to the native module
gamepad.setEmitFn(gamepad.applyEmit)

module.exports = gamepad
```